# Making Network call to some unknown ip-address

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

My unity desktop application is making call to an unknown ip-address. I have removed all network related code and calls from my unity application but still its making some network call. I am attaching an image of TCP/IP sniffer which will give you idea of network call. In that image see for highlighted lines in blue color with build.exe process name. I have to stop this network call. Because of this its giving firewall warning on some pc's whose image is also attached below. Thanks in advance.

[image: TCP/IP sniffer image]

[image: Firewall warning on running my game exe]

Comment: Is it debug mode build or release? My quess is it is related with debuging.

Comment: It is a standalone exe made from unity.

Comment: Yes, I know - but still my question remains. It looks like your build is in debug mode, so it is listning for clients. It is somehow ready to connect with debug tools.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make a release build. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Unity3D Editor go to File -> Build Settings -> And here check if it is set to Debug and chenge it to Release